# Does n >> 3 or n & 3 offer any advantage over n/8 or n % 8 respectively?

Tags: java, real-time

In my program memory and cpu time are constraints also this calculation will be done around 50000 times every second. Will there be a performance gain if bitwise operators are used over arithmetic ?

Comment: Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code when asking questions

Comment: @ElliottFrisch *"They perform identically"* Do they? Do you have a reference to a benchmark with that?

Comment: It may be worth noting that they don't produce the same results. And also 50,000 Hz isn't very much, at least outside of some embedded.

Comment: My advice would be pick the version that seems the most natural (and most correct!), and leave it to the JIT compiler's optimizer to pick the faster version.  Note that the optimal code is liable to be hardware dependent.  Especially if you are targeting platforms with different ISAs.

Comment: I know this is the typical statement but its too important to not post it each time: Write readable code. Do not do premature optimization, you will likely end up producing slower code and sacrificing readability. Measure your performance, only if you identified a real issue at that spot, only then optimize and then confirm with another measurement that you did not make it worse.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch it's *signed* remainder and *signed* division, even with optimizations they end up more complicated than a bitwise-AND and a shift respectively. So you're basically saying there is *litterally no difference* between an AND instruction, and an AND instruction plus some extras. The difference is small enough to make an accurate benchmark tricky, but it's too late to move the goalposts now.

Comment: @harold I'm simply not invested enough to back up my assertion, but in my own (admittedly limited) testing (some time ago) they behaved identically. But adding the weasel-y parentheticals doesn't really clarify anything, does it? Also, remember the JIT gets a pass to optimize things too.

Comment: I'm suprised that it's not marked as duplicate (there are few similar questions) or that it needs more clarity, cause of max size of word in processor, if the method runs parallely, cores, etc. What does memory have to do about it, does the results needs to be stored? If the runtime input data exceeds the ram then it needs to be stored on hard or flash or cached. OP said "cpu", so I won't wonder about "gpu" performance, but still here are few other types of CPUs . Is one of those operations a single statement in a method or more?

Comment: Offtop, @StephenC could you comment with some sources how the JIT in Java really works? Which methods or their calls are being compiled by JIT? What happens is the method parameter is an array or a list, so it could have wide range of sizes? I'm really curious about it now since I'm following this question from the moment in which it was published and almost all of the resources I've read were superficial on JIT topic. Thanks in advance

Comment: 1) No, but you can look at the source code. 2) Your question is too broad.

Answer (score 3):

It is highly unlikely that it would make any difference; CPUs wouldn't care about this sort of thing for decades.

In general, if you're worried about performance before you have any actual indication that the performance is below your needs – you're going to have a bad time. Modern hardware, and the JVM's optimising code is so incredibly complicated, even the JVM performance engineers themselves are on record that they have a very hard time just looking at code and then guessing if it can be made faster with cheap tricks like trying to replace a division by a bitshift.

The solution is to simply never engage in that sort of thing: If you have performance needs, write them down, and use profilers to figure out where to look (because generally 99% of the CPU resources are spent on 1% or less of the code – so before starting performance measurements, you need to know *what* to measure).

Once you know, use [JMH](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-performance/jmh.html) to actually test performance. That's what it is for.

*IF* JMH tells you that the bitshift is faster (I highly doubt it), know that this result does not necessarily translate to other CPU architecture.

Answer (score 1):

My observations of doing some simple testing would indicate yes, it makes a difference. No I didn't use JMH so I know I'll get some push back. But regardless of the order of testing the bitwise operations were always observed to be faster.  I can't say if faster equates to advantage but until proven otherwise I will continue to favor them when possible.

- `(i&1) == 1` is faster than `i%2 == 1`
- `i>>3` is faster than `i/8`

And I have seen this in the API code before, documented as being faster but I haven't tried it.

- `a<<6 + a<<5 + a<<2 vs a*100`

And then there is this for the bit shifting.

[Arithemetic Benchmark](https://gist.github.com/ejain/69796781f773ed64e430)